# .htaccess for static seo urls in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using seo user friendly in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444151/using-seo-user-friendly-in-php)

I have 3 PHP files: index1.php, index2.php and index3.php

Lets assume I want to have the following SEO paths:

```
/seo-path1/

/seo-path2/

/seo-path3/
```

How I could configure the .htaccess file so when a request comes from these sub folder, it redirects to their respective PHP file?

```
/seo-path1/ ---> goes to index1.php

/seo-path2/ ---> goes to index2.php

/seo-path3/ ---> goes to index3.php
```

Thanks in advance.
Greets.
Jose.

Comment: For more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444151/using-seo-user-friendly-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^seo-path1/$ /index1.php
RewriteRule ^seo-path2/$ /index2.php
RewriteRule ^seo-path3/$ /index3.php
```