# php user and SEO friendly URL

Tags: php, permalinks, slug

I'm trying to change my default url with its parameter from

```
localhost/webiste/posts.php?name=what-is-btc
```

to

```
 localhost/webiste/posts.php/what-is-btc
```

I've tired to main htaccess code `RewriteRule ^post([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  post?name=$1 [NC]`

But it's not working, can anyone please help me find a way to get it to work?

NB. I'm calling my data dynamically from database and I'm using php get to the name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using seo user friendly in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444151/using-seo-user-friendly-in-php)

Comment: Hi @matronator that's kinda what I was looking for, but that didn't answer my Q. I've also checked others but none are working, + I've updated the question here.

Comment: I think you have a mistake in your `RewriteRule`. I think it should look like this:
`RewriteRule ^post/([A-Za-z0-9-]+?)/?$ /post.php?name=$1 [NC, L]`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `.php` in your `RewriteRule` and also a leading slash.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^post/([A-Za-z0-9-]+?)/?$ /post.php?name=$1 [NC, L]
```

Comment: Thanks! and sorry for late response.